# Incrementally populating a list with a sliding effect

Tags: design, gui

I have seen a very nice effect in many applications which i don't how how it is achieved.

There is, usually, a list (eg. with emails) and the app populates it gradually with the emails putting them in order. They usually have a sliding effect to place the emails in the right line in the list.

Now, what I would like to find out is how they create the incremental population of the list. To become more specific; if I had to do this, I would retrieve the list of emails sorted by date directly from the database. Then I would populate the list. This means I would not receive the sorted emails gradually and then present them in the list.

Does anyone know how they do this? I tried to find a video but, unfortunately, I don't even know how to search for the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your question (as falsly interpreted, see comments) is basically about two concepts:

1. how to lazy-load items (data related)
2. how to animate inserting list items (gui related)

both topics are technology dependent and might be named differently. 
The first one is usually achieved with a datasource or dataprovider that is able to "**lazy-load**" data ("pagination" might also be a term used).
The second one is usually achieved with a gui component called "list" or "listview" (search for "**animating** insertion/deletion of **list view** items + name-of-technology").

Many modern frameworks already provide such capabilities.

Comment: I don't think the question is about lazy-loading or how to animate. I know about both concepts. Why do you think so? What I don't see in this effect, is how they make the filling of the in such way that the items seem to arrive asynchronously the moment they are available all together in one list

Comment: mh. You dont want to load your data incrementally, but want to have the items slide in independently? Are you looking for a [staggered animation](http://materializecss.com/transitions.html)?

Comment: The effect I have seen is similar to the staggered animation (BTW I didn't knwo the term so thanks for this) but the emails don't follow the order of the list. They seem to arrive randomly and then they are inserted in the correct place in the list

Comment: Seems to be a custom animation. So basically the list is initially unordered with the items in the list, but in the wrong place? Then the items are sorted so that they are ordered? Maybe update your question and describe in more detail and be very precise, because its not really clear